# Overlap background colour with image but not the content

Tags: html, css

Please see JS fiddle below, hopefully this will make sense. Currently i have added a negative margin on the image and the image goes on top of the entire div (red bock), what i want is for the image to go on top of the red background colour but not the content (the text).

```css
.coloredBlock {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
}

.imageBlock img {
  margin-left: -120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6 coloredBlock">
    <h1>This is a text</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 imageBlock">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added this to code so it goes on everything:

```
.coloredBlock h1{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mwtxazrr/

Comment: Wow cant believe it was that simple. That seems to do what i need. Will give it a go in my project and see. Thanks!